# How to solve this error "RawText must be wrapped in explicit text component" for react-native component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

[When I add click event for the button it shows this error in ios simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQq77.png)

```
renderLastSlide(index) {
  if (index === this.props.data.length - 1) {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Button rounded light>
            <Text>Light</Text>
            onPress={this.props.onComplete}
          </Button>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

What's the problem with this code that causes this error?

Comment: Your indentation is too bad, please edit this. After fix, you can see your error yourself.

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify the event on any element.

Specify `onPress` on Button:

```
<Button rounded light onPress={this.props.onComplete}>
    <Text>Light</Text>    
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the onPress parameter out of the button, so put it inside of it.

```
renderLastSlide(index) {
if (index === this.props.data.length - 1) {
  return (
    <Container>
        <Content>
            <Button rounded light onPress={this.props.onComplete}>
                <Text>Light</Text>
            </Button>
        </Content>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The error was disappeared while button event is not working when you click on it. It seems an error with react-navigation because all needed scripts are added in screen and app.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Hai you need to put onPress inside of Button.

```
renderLastSlide(index) {
  if (index === this.props.data.length - 1) {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Button 
            title= 'hai' 
            onPress={this.props.onComplete} // Add here
            rounded
            light
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
```

If you want to use Text component, I think prefer use TouchableOpacity than Button. So we can add style on the title.